# AlaSql Rows and Columns formatting when exporting to excel (.xls)

Tags: excel, formatting, alasql

I am using AlaSql version 0.4.2. I am exporting to excel through following way :

```
var mystyle = {
     headers: true,
     sheetid: 'Counter Correction',
  };

            //Create XLS format using alasql.js file.
            var excelHistoricalFileName = "HistoricalDataExport_" + $rootScope.Park_Name + "_" + $rootScope.turbineName + "_" + $rootScope.selectedTurbineSerialNum + ".xls";

            var excelObj = alasql('SELECT * INTO XLS("' + excelHistoricalFileName + '",?) FROM ?', [mystyle, data]);
```

The output excel is attached for reference at link : https://github.com/agershun/alasql/issues/966

I need the following through alasql formatting options :

Row 1, Column A, and Column B should be freezed.

All column should be angle aligned as mentioned in the screenshot. ExcelFormatting.png